# PL/SQL Exceptions

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, plsql

```
begin

  begin

     do something;

  exception

    when no_data_found then
      raise_application_error(-20000,"Message");

  end;

 exception

    when others then
        raise_application_error(-20000,"Other message");

 end;
```

My problem is when the compiler catches the "Message" error it alsos catches the "Other message" error. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to put them in the same exception block.

If you put `when others` in a separated block, it will alwasy be raised, as... there's no `already catched` exception to exclude from `others` in that block.

From doc

> The WHEN OTHERS clause is used to trap all remaining exceptions that have not been handled by your Named System Exceptions and Named Programmer-Defined Exceptions.

So

```
exception

    when no_data_found then
      raise_application_error(-20000,"Message");

    when others then
      raise_application_error(-20000,"Other message");

end;
```